# openvswitch 2.3.2 not working on FreeBSD 10.1 Release

Tags: kernel, freebsd, openvswitch

I Installed openvswitch 2.3.2 using the ports on FreeBSD 10.1. but i'm not able to make `ovs` work properly. In particular i launched all the configuration lines recommended by the official openvswitch installation guide but a simple command such as `ovs-vsctl add-br br0` hangs. So I tried to launch `/usr/local/share/openvswitch/scripts/ovs-ctl start`

and I get the following:

```
ovsdb-server: /var/run/openvswitch/ovsdb-server.pid: already running as pid 1320, aborting
Starting ovsdb-server ... failed!
system ID not configured, please use --system-id ... failed!
Configuring Open vSwitch system IDs.
/usr/local/share/openvswitch/scripts/ovs-ctl: modprobe: not found
Inserting openvswitch module ... failed!
Enabling remote OVSDB managers.
```

If i go and see which `ovs` processes are active i get these:

```
root       1319  0.0  0.3  39716   6200  -  I<s   6:13PM   0:00.00 ovsdb-server: monitoring pid 1320 (healthy) (ovsdb-server
root       1320  0.0  0.3  39716   6416  -  S<    6:13PM   0:01.02 ovsdb-server -vconsole:emer -vsyslog:err -vfile:info --re
```

So it seems that ovsdb is already running.
What am I doing wrong. I'm beginning to think that `ovs` is not supported in kernel mode in FreeBSD, but that's strange. It doesn't specifically say that anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OVS doesn't use kernel module under FreeBSD; instead it does forwarding in userspace (possibly using netmap, if supported by a given physical interface; it was actually used during netmap development).

That said, IIRC things should "just work".  Filing a Problem Report (https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla/) might be a good idea.